# Need Help on Basic HTML and JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a webpage that, when you click, it adds a point. I also want that, when A checkbox is checked, each click adds 5 points. I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Click to add points!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var hey = 3;
        var points = 0;
        function addPoint(number)
        {   
        points = points + number;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
        };  
        function checkBox()
        {
        var chkBox = document.getElementById("extraPoints").checked;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <html onclick="
        checkBox();
        if (chkBox == true)
        {
        addPoint(5);
        }
        else
        {
        addPoint(1);
        }">
        <body>
        <p align="center">Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
        <p align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="extraPoints" /></p>
        <p id="writeHere"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would also like to point out that I can't use jQuery.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi doggo, how u doin

Comment: @BartekPacia lol how tf did you find this

Comment: @doggo ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: It's nice to see how far I've gotten in 3 years lol

Comment: yeah. at least you stopped using "var"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the adding part inside of `checkBox`.

```js
function addPoint(number) {
    points = points + number;
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = points;
};

function checkBox() {
    var chkBox = document.getElementById("extraPoints").checked;
    addPoint(chkBox ? 5 : 1); 
}

var hey = 3;
var points = 0;
```

```html
<html onclick="checkBox();">
<p align="center">Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
<p align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="extraPoints" /></p>
<p id="writeHere"></p>
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use following approach.

**Note**: You can adjust the added points as you wish.

```js
var points = 0, //initial value 
    elem = document.getElementById('points'), //get span holding the value
    box = document.getElementById('extraPoints'); //get the checkbox

    document.addEventListener('click', function(){ //add click event on whole document
       box.checked ? points += 5 : points += 1 //if checkbox checked, add +5 - if not, add +1
       elem.innerHTML = points; //actualize the value in the span
    });
```

```html
<p align="center">Points: <span id="points">0</span></p>
<p align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="extraPoints" /></p>
<p id="writeHere"></p>
```